# Setting up weweave commerce and traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to setup weweave commerce with docker. But on step 4 it

> Use a cloud native edge router like Traefik (or nginx or haproxy): 
>   Route all incoming requests to /api/ to the backend.
>   Route all other incoming requests to the frontend.

How can I do this? I can't find it in the weweave docs and I don't understand the traefik docs.

**Update:** I built it from source now and it works. I will try the answer that is given me and will react if it works so if you have the same question you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this up-and-running with the following compose file.
Create a `config.json` file in a new folder with the following content:

```
{
    "database": {
        "driver": {
            "type": "mysql",
            "host": "mysql",
            "port": 3306,
            "username": "root",
            "password": "my-secret-pw",
            "database": "commerce"
        },
        "logging": ["error", "warn"]
    },
    "basePath": "/",
    "session": {
        "secret": "fkj49l7WwjUtqcfLZKlLA269J28kC4uL",
        "issuer": "https://change.me",
        "lifetime": "12h"
    },
    "importTldListOnStart": true
}
```

Create a `docker-compose.yml` in the same folder with the following content:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # The reverse proxy service (Traefik)
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik  # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"      # The HTTP port
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-secret-pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: commerce

  commerce:
    image: weweave/commerce
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - "mysql"
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/usr/src/app/config.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:commerce.docker.localhost;PathPrefix:/api/"
      - "traefik.port=3000"

  commerce-www:
    image: weweave/commerce-www
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "commerce"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:commerce.docker.localhost"
```

Bring up the whole stuff with
`docker-compose up -d`

Then open browser and navigate to: http://commerce.docker.localhost

Comment: @GameMaster2030 Now, after my merged PR it's official: https://github.com/weweave/commerce#using-with-docker-compose